# Cannot get value from async function

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm trying to get the result of `async` function on `ngOnInit`.

On **.ts** file, I add this function:

```
async load()
{ 
    this.picaes = await this.userService.getAffectedExpertisesPromiseSE(25);
    console.log("-Inside load--------------" + this.picaes);
    return this.picaes;
}
```

On **ngOnInit**, I call this `async` funtion:

```
console.log("-Outside load--------------" + this.load());
```

On the file **service.user.ts**, I made this call:

```
async getAffectedExpertisesPromiseSE(id: number): Promise<any>
{
    var url= `${this.baseUrl}/users/expertisesObj/${id}`;
    var result= await (await fetch(url)).text();
    return result;
}
```

That produces:

> -Outside load--------------[object Promise]
>
> -Inside load--------------[{"id":1,"name":"Angular","selected":true},{"id":2,"name":"SpringBoot","selected":true},{"id":3,"name":"Primefaces","selected":true}]

So my problem is that I can't get the result on the console **Outside load**.

Could you please tell me what I missed ?.
Big thanks.

Comment: `const v = await this.load(); console.log(v);`

Comment: Hello Sir @Reactgular, thanks for your reply. I got **'await' expression is only allowed within an async function** on sublime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Async function returns a promise not your expected output. Therefore you will not be getting the values on this.load(). Instead change your code to:

```
this.load().then((data) => {
   console.log('Outside load--------------' +data);
})
```

Comment: Hello Sir @Indragith, thanks a lot for your reply. But, I know that. But I'd like to get result outside **then**. Have you please any idea about solving that?. Big thanks Sir.

Comment: Initialize some variable in your component. Inside then, you can assign the data to that variable.

Comment: Otherwise you can move that load function outside of ngOnInit and declare a new async function for loading data which will remove the error ' 'await' expression is only allowed within an async function'

Comment: Yes Sir @Indragith, that's what I did,  `async load()` outside **ngOnInit** as presented on my question.

Comment: I tried `let list: Expertise[] = [];

      this.load().then((data) => 
      {   
          list = data;
          console.log('IN load --------------' + data);
      })

      console.log("-OUT load --------------" + list);`, but I got **nothing** on OUT

Comment: Second console log will get executed before the then function. You need to wait until the data gets loaded.

Comment: Ok Sir, thanks, but where I go to add **wait** in such case ?. I tried `const v = await this.load(); console.log(v);` on **ngOnInit**, but I got on sublime **'await' expression is only allowed within an async function**Big thanks.

Comment: If you want to execute anything with the data, do it inside the then function. then function will wait until data gets loaded

Comment: Ok Sir, that's what I did `let list: Expertise[] = []; this.load().then((data) => { list = data; console.log('IN load --------------' + data); }) console.log("-OUT load --------------" + list);`, Are you agree with that ?.

Comment: Call some function inside then. let list: Expertise[] = []; this.load().then((data) => { this.list = data; console.log('IN load --------------' + data); this.someFunction()}); someFunction() {console.log("-OUT load --------------" + this.list);}. Now it will work

Comment: Yes Sir @Indragith, you're right. It works as well. Big thanks. Also, i can use `XMLHttpRequest` to maintain synchrnous call.

Answer (score 2):

Why not trying using `XMLHttpRequest` instead of `async`

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:6227/api/auth/users', false);  
request.send(null);
```

You can use [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), this may help you maintaing synchrnous call.

HTH.

Comment: Yes, that way gives me the right response. Big thanks.